# Cross Domain OData filter on title breaking with & in the field

Tags: sharepoint-addin, cross-list

I am attempting to do a cross domain request from my app.

Document Library Title name is   !@$^&()-+={[}]|;MEEPBEEP    with the Server URL of  MEEPBEEP

In accessing the host web  in my request executor my function is as follows

```
function findDL() {
var executor;
var dfd = new jQuery.Deferred();
executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
executor.executeAsync({
    url: appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/Web/Lists" +
        "?@target='" + hostweburl + "'" +
        "&$select=Id, Title&$top=5000&$filter=Title eq '" + ListInfo.oldName + "'",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    headers: {
        Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
    },
    success: successHandler(dfd),
    error: errorHandler(dfd)
});
return dfd;
}

function successHandler(dfd, data) {
return dfd.resolve;
}
function errorHandler(dfd, data, errorCode, errorMessage) {
console.log(errorMessage);
return dfd.reject;
}
```

When I attempt this  without  special character it works fine but when I add in the &  my  request 404 on me.

To continue testing  I opened up postman and attempted to find the list by using

`hostWEB/_api/web/lists?$filter=Title eq ' listname'`

and without special characters I am able to get  the list information.

When I  search for a list name with a & in it  It 404 on me.    When I change the &  to %26
I get the following JSON returned to me

```
{
    "d": {
        "results": []
    }
}
```

So clearly SharePoint can find the list  but it's not returning any information to me.   I have add the OData Select Statements  to select the columns I wish to see but I still get a blank JSON result.

An attempt with   `GetByTitle`  returns  the list information.  Sadly I don't believe I can use this endpoint   as it is a cross domain request.

If I am unable to fix this issue  I simply make a workflow that will use the `GetByTitle`  but I would rather not lose the code I have worked one.

The following request worked:

```
var executor;
var dfd = new jQuery.Deferred();
executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
executor.executeAsync({
    url: appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('" + ListInfo.oldName + "')?@target='" + encodeURIComponent(hostweburl) + "'",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    headers: {
        Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
    },
    success: successHandler(dfd),
    error: errorHandler(dfd)
});
return dfd;
```

Still  I am left wondering why the  OData Query gives me a blank result set.   While the fix does seem to work,   It leaves me to wonder if this is a bug with SharePoint OData  Filtering options.

Comment: Are you encoding `hostweburl`? I'm not 100% certain, but I believe it needs to be encoded.  I noticed your code snippet is missing an ending single quote (').  Is this just a typo when copying the code over?

Comment: As for your belief about being unable to use GetByTitle, you can use it.  I've never had any trouble with `/web/lists/getbytitle()` in Cross Domain calls.  Almost all the REST I've been doing lately is Cross Domain, and I've yet to find any discrepancies in what you can do.

Comment: It was an error thanks for point that out.

I Tried to use the url 

    appweburl +        "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('" + ListInfo.oldName + "')" +
             "?@target='" + hostweburl + "'"     

but  that didnt seem to work either.  Is this correct format to use?

Comment: Try  `encodeURIComponent(hostweburl)`

Comment: Just to verify, your REST request works in Postman, but fails when converting to Cross Domain request?

Comment: awesome worked like a charm.    

Im still confused why the OData  Query     with the & changed to %26   would return  a blank result set instead of 404  or item not found.   but hey it works

Comment: well  I had to change  the cross Domain request   to where it was

hostWEB /_api/web/lists?$filter=Title eq ' listname'

in postman.  Meaning I took off the cross domain   of the whole  appweburl/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/
and the  ?@target= '" + hostweburl + "'  

to just the hostweburl/web/list?$filter   to  test it in postman.   I didnt think I could do cross domain request without the app web credentials.

Comment: Actually I think im losing it.    I mispelled encodeURIComponent(hostweb)  and my javascript faulted out.   That didnt fix it and I still cant find my DocumentLibrary by name

Comment: Can you edit your question with the code you're using now?  And can you include all details for the request? ie, `executor.executeAsync({ url: ....` and so forth.